# Remove first TD of a TR Table in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove a td at runtime using Javascript only (no JQuery intended). Here is my table :

```
<table id = "tab">
    <tr>
        <td>
            test 1
        </td>
        <td>
            test 2
        </td>
        <td>
            test 3
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is what I tryied :

```
function removeFirstTD() {
    var element = document.getElementById("tab");
    element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
}
```

Note that this function works and I execute it by doing this :

```
<body onload = "removeFirstTD();">
    <!-- the tab is here -->
</body>
```

The problem is that it seems to erase the `<tr>` because I didn't scope the tr before requesting remove the td. May someone help me doing this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go down one more level?

```
element.firstChild.removeChild(element.firstChild);
```

Comment: @Zeratops This [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/t3u9dntd/) with the HTML you've in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the simplest way is to use [HTMLTableElement Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement):

```
function removeFirstTD() {
    var element = document.getElementById("tab");
    element.rows[0].deleteCell(0);
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95668fwn/).

Answer (score 1):

Use can also use querySelector. It picks the first element that matches it like this;

```
function removeFirstTD() {
    var element = document.querySelector("#tab tr td");
    element.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to white space (between the `table` and `tr`, and `tr` and `td`) this creates TEXTNODES which will be the first children, you would have to be more specific:

```
function removeFirstTD() {
    var element = document.getElementById('tab');
    var firstRow = element.getElementsByTagName('TR')[0];
    var firstColumn = firstRow.getElementsByTagName('TD')[0];
    firstColumn.remove();
}
```

But you might find this simpler and more reliable:

```
function removeFirstTD() {
    document.querySelector('#tab tr td').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. `td` elements belong to the `tr` elements (and technically the `tr` elements should belong to a `tbody` element, not the `table` directly). You need to get the `tr` elements then find their first children.

```
function removeFirstTD() {
    var element = document.getElementById("tab");
    var tr = element.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var j = tr.length; 
    while (j--){
        tr[j].removeChild(tr[j].firstChild);
    }
}
```

Note that `firstChild` might be whitespace or some other entity that is no the first `td` element, and you should add a check for that before removing that child.

Comment: Thank you for anwsering. I am going to try this one, good job for the explainations !

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table class="u-full-width">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <strong><td>Joke</td></strong>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>This is a joke</td>
            </tr>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I'm adding this to give a step by step procedure for beginners like me looking for this answer.
Let's say above is how our table looks

1. First, get a DOM reference to the table body `let tbody = document.querySelector('u-full-width').getElementsByTagName('tbody')`
2. The above statements return a HTML Collection. So, we take the zero index of that collections `tbody = tbody[0]`
3. `tbody.removeChild(tbody.firstElementChild)` `firstElementChild`ignores text and comment nodes